# How to create row headers spanning two columns in a Handsontable?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, handsontable

I'm trying to create two-column row headers in a Handsontable but it is not happening:

```
     ------------------------                                       
    | C1 | C2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |                                 
    | ------------------------                                
    | R1 | R1 |                             
    | ---------                                
    | R2 | R2 | These are copy paste area                           
    |----------                                 
    | R3 | R3 |
    -----------
```

I have tried the following:

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, 
{
    minRows:rlength,
    minCols:clength,
    rowHeaders: [["R1","R2","R3"],["R1","R2","R3"]],
    colHeaders: colHead, // This is working 
    contextMenu: false,

    maxCols:clength,
    maxRows:max_row,
    outsideClickDeselects: true,
    removeRowPlugin: false
});
```

In `rowHeaders`  I'm passing the Array of Array but it is showing in one row. 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: My suggestion would be to make your first column Read-Only and render this column the same as the Header column. This is of course a cosmetic solution since Handsontable doesn't support two headers as Steve Chambers mention in his answer but maybe it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Handontable's [rowHeaders](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.1/Options.html#rowHeaders) member doesn't support more that one row header column. The documentation only mentions passing a single dimension array and [from trying it out](http://jsfiddle.net/b79Lx2m7/), it treats each element in the outermost array as a single row header string (so converting the inner arrays into comma-separated strings).

Since the rendering is different for the row header column, it would seem that the only sensible solution here would be to somehow combine the multiple row header values into single header values - i.e. something like this:

```
rowHeaders: ["R1 R1", "R2 R2", "R3 R3"]
```